# jquery ui plugin/widget load order when adding individually

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using multiple jquery ui widgets for my project and as the project has progressed I've just added what I've needed to the bottom of the list but now I get some errors.  In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594579) is saying some widgets inherit properties/functions from others so what is best order to arrange the script tags for all the widgets to work properly without errors?

Here are jquery files I'm using in the order they are in the HTML

1. jquery.1.7.2.min.js
2. jquery.ui.core.min.js
3. jquery.ui.widget.min.js
4. jquery.ui.position.min.js
5. jquery.effects.core.min.js
6. jquery.ui.tooltip.min.js
7. jquery.ui.dialog.min.js
8. jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js
9. jquery.ui.tabs.min.js
10. jquery.ui.selectable.min.js
11. jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js
12. jquery.ui.menu.min.js
13. jquery.ui.button.min.js
14. jquery.ui.draggable.min.js
15. jquery.ui.mouse.min.js
16. jquery.ui.resizable.min.js

Thanks

Comment: What widgets are you using? as the other question says, they just have to be loaded in an order that they are used such that one that relies upon another comes after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the compiled UI file is looks like it might be this:

1. UI Core
2. Widget
3. Mouse
4. Draggable
5. Droppable
6. Resizeable
7. Selectable
8. Sortable
9. Effects Core
10. All effects included alphabetically
11. Accordion
12. Autocomplete
13. Button
14. Datepicker
15. Dialog
16. Menu
17. Menubar
18. Popup
19. Positon
20. Progress bar
21. Slider
22. Spinner
23. Tabs
24. Tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what widgets are you trying to use. You should always import jquery first, and then look at the widget dependencies. 
You can also "build your own jquery" [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) and any required dependencies will automatically be checked automatically.