# The "base" function in jquery-ui.widget undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Something peculiar is happening for me with jquery-ui. I'm importing several pieces of jquery-ui separately in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../third-party/jquery-1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Yet, when I load the HTML, I get `undefined is not a function` when my javascript attempts to use `$.widget`. The offending line in jquery-ui.widget.js is:

```
basePrototype = new base();
```

I'm perplexed. Did I miss a dependency somewhere? It doesn't seem like I did, but I must be missing something. I also tried it with the jquery-ui.custom.js that jquery-ui's website provided instead, to no avail. I'm always including jquery first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is relevant:

[jQuery.ui.draggable.js and jQuery.ui.widget.js conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594579/jquery-ui-draggable-js-and-jquery-ui-widget-js-conflict)

Try if top answer in this question works for you.

Comment: Well, I definitely had to include jquery-ui.widget before jquery-ui.mouse. Nonetheless, it still gave me the same error using jquery-ui.custom with all of this, so you'd think the combined javascript would have the correct order of dependencies.